# Scheduled processes running twice simultaneously in Openbravo (using Quartz)

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, openbravo

I'm not quite sure whether this is more of an Openbravo issue or more of a Quartz issue, but we have some manual processes that run on schedules via Openbravo `ProcessRequest` objects (OB v2.50MP24), but it seems that the processes are running twice, at the exact same time. Openbravo extends the Quartz platform for their scheduling. I've tried to resolve this issue on my own by ensuring that my process classes extend this class:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openbravo.dal.service.OBDal;
import org.openbravo.model.ad.ui.ProcessRequest;
import org.openbravo.scheduling.ProcessBundle;
import org.openbravo.service.db.DalBaseProcess;

public abstract class RBDDalProcess extends DalBaseProcess {

    @Override
    protected void doExecute(ProcessBundle bundle) throws Exception {
        org.quartz.Scheduler sched = org.openbravo.scheduling.OBScheduler
                .getInstance().getScheduler();
        int runCount = 0;
        synchronized (sched) {
            List<org.quartz.JobExecutionContext> currentlyExecutingJobs = (List<org.quartz.JobExecutionContext>) sched
                    .getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
            for (org.quartz.JobExecutionContext jec : currentlyExecutingJobs) {
                ProcessRequest processRequest = OBDal.getInstance().get(
                        ProcessRequest.class, jec.getJobDetail().getName());
                if (processRequest == null)
                    continue;
                String processClass = processRequest.getProcess()
                        .getJavaClassName();
                if (bundle.getProcessClass().getCanonicalName()
                        .equals(processClass)) {
                    runCount++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (runCount > 1) {
            System.out.println("Process "
                    + bundle.getProcessClass().getSimpleName()
                    + " is already running. Cancelling.");
            return;
        }

        doRun(bundle);
    }

    protected abstract void doRun(ProcessBundle bundle);

}
```

This worked fine when I tested by requesting the process to run immediately twice at the same time. One of them cancelled. However, it's not working on the scheduled processes. I have S.o.p's set up to log when the processes start, and looking at the logs shows each line of the output twice, each line one right after the other.

I have a sneaking suspicion that it's because the processes are either running in two completely different threads that don't know about each others' processes, however, I'm not sure how to verify my suspicions or, if I am correct, what to do about it. I've already verified that there is only one instance of each of the `ProcessRequest` objects stored in the database.

Has anyone else experienced this, know why they might be running twice, or know what I can do to prevent them from simultaneously running?

Comment: Did you try to check thread dump while debugging (I mean which threads are running)?

Comment: kamaci, I would try it, but the same scenario does not happen on my development machine; it only happens on the production server, which I don't know how to debug threads on due to there being only command-line access (so I can't use something like VisualVM).

Comment: I suggest you to use logging your and writing it to a log file. Maybe it can show us something? On the other hand if it is another machine instead of yours and other developers use it too, be aware of nobody is reaching that machine and making test while you are testing.

Comment: What should I be writing to the log?

Comment: can you check the version of Quartz shipped with OBv2.50MP24? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common reasons for a double Job execution are the following:

**EDITED:**

> - Your application is deployed in a clustered environment and you have not configured Quartz to run in a cluster environment.
> - Your application is deployed more than once. There are many cases where the application is deployed twice especially in Tomcat server. As a consequence the QuartzInitializerListener is invoked twice and the Jobs are executed twice. In case you use Tomcat server and you are defining contexts explicitly in server.xml, you should turn off automatic application deployment or specify deployIgnore. Both the autoDeploy set to true and the context element existence in server.xml, have as a consequence the twice deployment of the application. Set autoDeploy to false or remove the context element from the server.xml.
> - Your application has been redeployed without unscheduling the current processes.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately the context is not explicitly defined in server.xml and we are not in a clustered environment.

Comment: OK, so it does seem that exploring problems with not *deployment* but *redeployment* after a build led me to find that somehow the scheduler gets "wonky" and is running scheduled processes twice, but if I unschedule the processes and reschedule them, the processes run only once. This seems kind of "cheap" to have to do to me but it will have to do for now, and since your answer led me to this discovery, Tolis, I will go ahead and give you the bounty. :)

Answer (score 2):

Quartz uses a thread pool for the jobs execution. So as you suspect, the `RBDDalProcess` will probably have separate instances a in separate thread and the counter check will fail.

One thing you can do is list the jobs registered in the Scheduler (you can get the Scheduler using the OB API as: `OBScheduler.getScheduler()`):

```
// enumerate each job group
for(String group: sched.getJobGroupNames()) {
    // enumerate each job in group
    for(JobKey jobKey : sched.getJobKeys(groupEquals(group))) {
        System.out.println("Found job identified by: " + jobKey);
    }
}
```

If  you see the same job added twice, check out [org.quartz.spi.JobFactory](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/spi/JobFactory.html) and the [org.quartz.Scheduler.setJobFactory](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#setJobFactory%28org.quartz.spi.JobFactory%29) method for controlling jobs instantiations.

Also make sure you have only one entry for this process in the 'Report and Process' table in Openbravo.

I have used `DalBaseProcess` in Openbravo 3.0 and I cannot confirm this behavior you're describing. Having this in mind it would be probably a good idea to checkout the reported bugs for Openbravov2.50MP24 and Quartz or post a thread in [Openbravo Forge](http://forge.openbravo.com/) forums with your problem.